# Javascript post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Probably a stupid question because I am not too good with JS.

I have a simple converter, when I enter in a textarea (onkeypress it fires a function). One problem is I don't want the whole HTML response, I want separe div as var.

I need the result and count. This is my script

```
function convert(){
 var convertTxt = $("textarea[name='unit']").val();
   $.post("convert.php",{convertVal: convertTxt}, function(data){
    $("#output").html(data);
   });}
```

With this I get the whole conver.php file but what I would like to get it inner html of two elements by Id. So for ex:

*convert.php*

```
echo "<div id='output'>$output</div>"
echo "<div id='count'>$count</div>"
```

The output I get after entering in a textarea
*convert.php*

```
<div id="output">this_has_been_converted</div> 
<div id="count">3</div>
```

I would like to parse the date from inner this div's to my index.php. With the script above I get everything, div, id's but I want to get only the date inside the divs (separately). Because in index.php I want to place them in different places not one next to the other.

Comment: what is the format of your returned data?

Comment: #output: long text
#count: integer

Comment: can you please put the data here.

Comment: <div id="output">this_has_been_converted</div>
<div id="count">3</div>

I would like to parse the date from inner this div's to my index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the data like this,

```
 $.post("convert.php", {
     convertVal: convertTxt
 }, function(data) {
     var output = $(data).filter("#output").text();
     var count = $(data).filter("#count").text();
     $("#output").html(output);
     $("#count").html(count);
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a method switch on your server-side file:

```
<?php
    var methodRequested = $_POST['method'];

    switch (methodRequested){
        case "callFirstLine": sendFirstLine();
        break;
        case "callSecondLine": sendSecondLine();
        break;
    }

    function sendFirstLine(){
        echo "<div id='output'>$output</div>";
    }

    function sendSecondLine(){
        echo "<div id='count'>$count</div>";
    }
?>
```

Then your AJAX should say:

```
$.post("convert.php?method=callFirstLine",{convertVal: convertTxt}, function(data){
    $("#output").html(data);
});}
```